# Fanning fire during Homa/Sacrifice

Tags: sacrifice, agni, homam

I have seen during homa/fire sacrifices air is blown by using fan (handheld fans/plates/etc.). I was always told that blowing through mouth is impure (because may be saliva dropping on fire).

However, I came across a book (in Tamil; screenshot attached) which quotes Devala and says one must not use fans (handheld fans, plates, etc.)...the book recommends using blow air from mouth through a tube.

This book does not mention which scripture this quote from Devala is. So, question is, **a)** what are the rules regarding fanning sacred fire? **b)** Is blowing air through mouth is allowed?

[image]

Comment: The quote is likely from directky from Devalasmṛti or a indirectly via a nibandha that quoted from the same. Besides the segment आयुः क्षीणं मुखोद्धमे means that one shouldn't fan holy fire by mouth because it reduces lifespan.